# Xperia Play skin on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

he,

I want to develop on Xperia Play, so how i can get Xperia play skin on android sdk emulator ?

Answer (score 1):

Although it's a little late to reply now. But might be helpful for anybody else looking for this information. 
There is no emulator skin available for Xperia PLAY but in case you need to configure your emulator to Xperia PLAY config, you can view the white paper specs here.

http://developer.sonymobile.com/wportal/devworld/downloads/download/sonyericssonxperiaplaywhitepaper?cc=gb&lc=en
If you wish to create a skin,you can also search for more resources related to button pictures at developer.sonymobile.com.

Thanks,
Anupam